# AngularJS - Directives - What's the reason behind the following syntax?

Tags: angularjs, syntax, angularjs-directive

My question is related to directories and two of its properties.

What is the reason that the parameters for the link function don't have a `$` sign as a prefix?

e.g

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                        scope.$watch("item.quantity", function () {
                            ctrl.updateTotal();
                        });
                    }
```

in contrast to the controller property:

```
controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                    }
```

I know that the first one is a link function and thus is written without a `$` sign.

But why make a difference? Is it partly because you can create your own `scope` in a directive and as a result the scope doesn't necessarily mean to be related with the `$scope` of the controller?

That would explain the `scope` parameter but I can't think of any explanation regarding the other ones.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention the `$` prefixes are not used with functions which are not injected by the $injector. So the `link: function (scope, element, attrs [,ctrl])` will not be injected. It always has the same parameters in the same order.

When dealing with functions where the dependency injection provides the arguments, you must use `$scope`, otherwise it won't be injected.

**TL;DR**

This is more or less to confuse Angular learners, but it is vital that you have to use positioned parameters for some functions (like postLink).

**Additional info and links**

For those of you who want to know the exact details, I recommend reading following chapters of AngularJS Guide:

- [Creating Directives that Communicate](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate), please read the paragraph above the [Summary](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#summary).
- [Comprehensive Directive API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api)

In the latter link you can see the directive definition object containing some methods with positioned parameters (please note that in this example there are many options which don't make sense in combination):

```
myModule.directive('directiveName', function factory(injectables) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    template: function(tElement, tAttrs) { ... },
    templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) { ... },
    // controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, otherInjectables) { ... },
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
      }
    },
    link: {
      pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
      post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
    }
    // or
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
  };
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

If you use a controller function in the DDO (abreviation for directive definition object), the arguments will be injected (hence the prefix `$`):

```
// ... somewhere in the DDO ...
controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, otherInjectables) { ... },
```

You can find documentation for the "special" injectables [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)

Sure there are more than the mentioned functions with positioned parameters, e.g. the $animate `enter()`, `leave()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is just calling a method with these specific objects as parameters. If we wanted to (but of course it goes against convention), we could name these parameters whatever we wanted to, as long as we retained the order they were being used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just out of curiosity, is exactly the same happing in in the controller function?

Comment: You are correct but only in case if you are using shorthand version of declaring our controller.

Comment: Continued...       But it could be an issue in case of longhand version. Longhand version is that it actually protects against minification. Minification may break your controllers if you decide to use the shorthand way, since it will rename your parameters to shorter names, like “a”. app.controller("MyCtrl",["$scope", "$http", function(a, b){
  console.log(a)
}]);  // longhand version after minification

Comment: Continued...   The longhand version protects from minification because the angular is now looking at the strings in the array for dependency injection and strings don’t get minified. Now order matters, the order of parameters for the function should correspond with the order they appeared in the array. To demonstrate, if we add a second dependency of “$http”, and second parameter “b”, if we log “a” we’ll still get the scope, and “b” will still be $http. However, if we change the order of the parameters to “b” as the first parameter, and log “b” we’ll get the scope again.

Comment: Continued...    So order does matter if we are using the longhand version, since we are declaring the order in the array.